# Is there a way to have calculations html width attribute?

Tags: html, css, attributes, width

I was wondering if it is possible to have calculations in HTML **width** attribute. Something like:

```
<SVG width="100%-10px">
```

or a CSS workaround for the same?

Answer (score 2):

As @Hunter suggested, you could use `calc()`, but I would advise against it, because:

> Due to the way browsers handle sub-pixel rounding differently, layouts using calc() expressions may have unexpected results.

source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Just use javascript, if it has to be that dynamic to ensure everything would look the same on all browsers.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <svg class="dynamic-width"></svg>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
var pixelsToSubtract = 10;
var svg = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic-width')[0];
svg.style.width = parent.getBoundingClientRect().width - 10 + 'px';
```

Comment: Unless the OP is planning on using multiplication or division (not supported on older Android versions), supporting IE 8, or Opera Mini, `calc()` should work just fine. But if not, then your JavaScript solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing you're looking for is the CSS calc() function http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Here is an example `width: calc(100% - 10px);`

You can use mathematical expression such as + - * /

Answer (score 1):

[calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) works just fine for this:

```css
svg {
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```